# Defining external path variable for python package on installation

Tags: python, package

If I have a Python package, `foo`, and I want a path variable that is user-defined during package installation (`foo.ext_path = '/Home/User_name/Data_files/foo_data'` or something), what is the best/recommended/most pythonic manner to accomplish this?  I do not want to include the data within the python package; this is something that is both necessary to run foo, and necessary for the user to provide.

Comment: Use environment variables maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Required configuration usually falls into the category of things belonging in an external configuration file.

The package can define a configuration file path, in posix this is usually something under `/etc`, and ask that the user populate it with appropriate entries for their configuration.

Best practice is for the package to create an example configuration file for example `/etc/my_package/my_package.example` or similar, to show all available configuration entries and example values.

Python has built in support for configuration files via [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html?highlight=cfg) though YAML based config files are usually easier to use and frequently more common.